# QML Treeview: How to get QModelIndex of childs

Tags: c++, qt, qml, qt5, qstandarditemmodel

I have a QML `TreeView` with a `QStandardItemModel` and use a `ItemSelectionModel` to manage the selection. The `ItemSelectionModel` wants a `QModelIndex` for its `select` function. How can I obtain the `QModelIndex` of children in my view?

The tree looks like this:

- file 1

  - task 1
  - task 2
- file 2

  - task 1

I want to select task2 when I click on it (I can have a MouseArea in the delegate) (so that the TreeView highlights it), and in order to do this, I must call `ItemSelectionModel.select` with the `QModelIndex` of task 2. But I don'
t know how I can get the QModelIndex of task2.

`QStandardItemModel` is derived from `QAbstractItemModel` and therefore provides an index function:

```
 virtual QModelIndex    index(int row, int column, const QModelIndex & parent = QModelIndex()) const
```

but to use this function I need to know the index of the parent. How can I get it from the view?

Comment: What childrens do you mean ?, that is, who is the parent?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To obtain the child you must first have the parent, so in the case of your scheme you must obtain *"file1"* and for this you must obtain his parent, and this parent is the `rootIndex` of the `TreeView`, so the sequence is: `rootIndex -> file1 -> task1`.

**main.cpp**

```
#include <QGuiApplication>
#include <QQmlApplicationEngine>
#include <QQmlContext>
#include <QStandardItemModel>

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    QCoreApplication::setAttribute(Qt::AA_EnableHighDpiScaling);

    QGuiApplication app(argc, argv);

    QStandardItemModel model;

    QStandardItem *item1 = new QStandardItem("file1");
    item1->appendRows({new QStandardItem("task1"), new QStandardItem("task2")});

    QStandardItem *item2 = new QStandardItem("file2");
    item2->appendRows({new QStandardItem("task1")});

    model.appendRow(item1);
    model.appendRow(item2);

    QQmlApplicationEngine engine;
    engine.rootContext()->setContextProperty("tree_model", &model);
    engine.load(QUrl(QStringLiteral("qrc:/main.qml")));
    if (engine.rootObjects().isEmpty())
        return -1;

    return app.exec();
}
```

**main.qml**

```
import QtQuick 2.9
import QtQuick.Window 2.2
import QtQuick.Controls 1.4
import QtQml.Models 2.11

Window {
    visible: true
    width: 640
    height: 480
    TreeView {
        id: treeView
        anchors.fill: parent
        model: tree_model
        selectionMode: SelectionMode.MultiSelection
        selection: ItemSelectionModel {
            id: ism
            model: tree_model
        }
        TableViewColumn {
            title: "Name"
            role: "display"
            width: 300
        }
        Component.onCompleted: {
            expandAll()

            var ix1 = tree_model.index(0, 0, treeView.rootIndex)
            var ix = tree_model.index(0, 0, ix1)
            ism.select(ix, ItemSelectionModel.Select)
        }
    }

    // https://forum.qt.io/topic/75395/qml-treeview-expand-method-not-working
    function expandAll() {
        for(var i=0; i < tree_model.rowCount(); i++) {
            var index = tree_model.index(i,0)
            if(!treeView.isExpanded(index)) {
                treeView.expand(index)
            }
        }
    }
}
```

[image]

**Update:**

To get the index of the item pressed you must use `styleData.index`:

```
import QtQuick 2.9
import QtQuick.Window 2.2
import QtQuick.Controls 1.4
import QtQml.Models 2.11

Window {
    visible: true
    width: 640
    height: 480
    TreeView {
        id: treeView
        anchors.fill: parent
        model: tree_model
        selectionMode: SelectionMode.MultiSelection
        selection: ItemSelectionModel {
            id: ism
            model: tree_model
        }
        TableViewColumn {
            title: "Name"
            role: "display"
            width: 300
        }
        itemDelegate: Item {
            Text {
                anchors.verticalCenter: parent.verticalCenter
                color: styleData.textColor
                elide: styleData.elideMode
                text: styleData.value

            }
            MouseArea{
                anchors.fill: parent
                onClicked: {
                    var ix = tree_model.index(0, 0, styleData.index)
                    ism.select(ix, ItemSelectionModel.Select)
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I should have been more specific. The selection should happen via a click onto the MouseArea of a delegate. And the problem is to find the right ix1 (here file1) in the MouseArea of task1.